# XSLT replace non ascii with space

Tags: xml, xslt, ascii

I have made this XSLT but just removes non-ASCII characters.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="charset" select="'@.1234567890 abcdefghilmnopqrstuvwzkyx ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVWZYKX'" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., $charset, ''), '')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to replace instead with a simple space.
Any clue?

Comment: Is there going to be a maximum length on the strings you are going to be adjusting?

Comment: yes max 150 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a maximum length of the text you will be replacing, you can simply define a variable consisting of 150 spaces, and use that in the translate expression.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="charset" select="'@.1234567890 abcdefghilmnopqrstuvwzkyx ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVWZYKX'" />
    <!-- 150 spaces -->
    <xsl:param name="spaces" select="'                                                                                                                                                      '" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., $charset, ''), $spaces)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use the `replace` function, which allows for regular expressions.

Comment: just perfect! thanks so much, i was banging my head already for a while.

Comment: This is a really nice technique.  I did not know that this could be done with XSLT 1.0.